# jQuery only last value saved inside event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm new to jQuery and trying to understand what is happening in the code below:

```
var data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
for (var key in data) {
    $("#id"+key).click(function() {
        $(".class"+key).hide();
    });
}
```

When I run this code, it will hide `class4` no matter which id I click. Why is this behaviour the case?

Also, how do I make `id1` hide `class1`, `id2` hide `class2`, and so on?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS. If `data` is an object where are the values? If `data` is an array you should be using brackets `[]`, and `for` loop instead of `for...in`

Comment: it probably wasn't as simple as 1,2,3,4 so the OP probably made a typing mistake when he was typing up the content of a fake piece of data so we can focus on the logic. Good eye lol I completely missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5g7RP/)

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var i = 0;i < data.length; i++) {    
    (function(key) {    
        $("#id"+key).click(function() {
            $(".class"+key).hide();
        });
    })(data[i])
}​
```

In your for each loop closure is created by handler click, but it points to `key` which is in global scope. And it is changed. In my code key points to scope created by additional function wrapping `.click` and `key` in it points to `key` in scope created by that function, each time it is new

`var data = {1, 2, 3, 4};` - this is not valid object definition. It should be like this:
`var data = {key:"value", key2:"value",...};` Example above will also work with correctly specified object. Just do not forget that you should also test `key` variable like this:
`if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...}` in order to filter out `.toString`, `.valueOf` etc (default object methods)

Or like a workaround - you always can get `key` to build a class name from clicked element 
ID.

```
$("#id"+key).click(function() {
    var className = ".class" + $(this).prop("id").replace("id", "");
    $(className).hide();
});
```

And no closure needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = { 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4 };
for (var key in data) {
   $("#id" + key).click(function () {
           $(".class" + this.id.substr(this.id.toString().length - 1, 1)).hide();
     });
}
```

Actually problems are

1. `var data = {1, 2, 3, 4};` is invalid for sure.
2. `$(".class"+key)` is evaluated at runtime on `click` event and at that time `key` holds `4` which was the last value assigned to it, So its wrong. So you should get that numeric value at runtime from clicker's `id` itself.